# How is your JVM 6 memory setting for JBOSS AS 5?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, settings

I'm using an ICEFaces application that runs over JBOSS, my currently heapsize is set to

-Xms1024m –Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

what is your recommendation to adjust memory parameters for JBOSS AS 5 (5.0.1 GA) JVM 6?

Comment: We can't possible give you a recommendation on that information. The fact that you're running ICEFaces isn't relevant.

Comment: tks skaffman. Say for example a little application (5 different pages) with JMS active,EJB3, and 10 to 50 users.

Comment: That's probably way more memory than you need, then. Do you have a specific question, or a reason to think your memory settings are wrong?

Comment: I was using only 512 of total heap size, and that was definitely too small. After increasing to 1024m the application works faster (at least from the user point of view). What about the perm size ?

Comment: Permgen size will not affect performance. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: There's a strange hyphen before -xmx, it would be helpful to get that fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/CargoMavenplugin-raisingPermGenforJBossAS5):

> AS 5 is known to be greedy when it comes to [PermGen](http://codingclues.eu/2008/permgen-space-exceptions-with-maven-due-to-memory-leak/). When starting, it often throws `OutOfMemoryException: PermGen Error`.

This can be particularly annoying during development when you are hot deploying frequently an application. In this case, JBoss QA recommends to *raise the permgen size, allow classes unloading and permgen sweep*:

```
-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

But this is more FYI, I'm not suggesting to apply this configuration blindly (as people wrote in comments, "if it ain't broken, don't fix it").

Regarding your heap size, always keep in mind: *the bigger the heap, the longer the major GC*. Now, when you say "it was definitely too small", I don't really know what this means (what errors, symptoms, etc). To my knowledge, a 1024m heap is actually pretty big for a webapp and should really be more than enough for most of them. Just beware of the major GC duration.

Comment: Great suggestions! JBoss 5 and 6M3 don't like "+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" though.  They say to use -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled instead.

Answer (score 0):

Heap: Start with 512 MB, set the cap to where you believe your app should never get, and not to make your server start swapping.

Permgen: That's usually stable enough, once the app reads all classes used in the app. If you have tested the app and it works with 256 MB, then leave it so.

Answer (score 0):

@wds: It's definitely not a good idea to set the heap maximum as high as possible for two reasons:

1. Large heaps make full GC take longer.   If you have PermGen scanning enabled, a large PermGen space will take longer to GC as well.
2. JBoss AS on Linux can leave unused I/O handles open long enough to make Linux clean them up forcibly, blocking all processes on the machine until it is complete (might take over 1 minute!).  If you forget to turn off the hot deploy scanner, this will happen much more frequently.

This would happen maybe once a week in my application until I:

1. decreased -Xms to a point where JBoss AS startup was beginning to slow down
2. decreased -Xmx to a point where full GCs happened more frequently, so the Linux I/O handle clean up stopped

For developers I think it's fine to increase PermGen, but in production you probably want to use only what is necessary to avoid long GC pauses.

Comment: Yes, sorry, terrible advice. I deleted it. Sorry for that, don't know what I was thinking.